# Azure VM to Azure Blob Storage Data Transfer Costs

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, blob, bandwidth, price

I have a system set up in Microsoft Azure where an Azure VM connects to Azure Blob store and downloads a file for processing. A new output file is generated and the uploaded back into the Azure Blob Store. The output file is several orders of magnitude larger than the input file.

The Azure VM accesses the blob storage through an endpoint like:- "https://xxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/". Where xxxxxx is the blob store name, redacted for privacy.

My question is, when I upload the output file into the Azure Blob store through that endpoint, does the traffic from the VM count as egress to the internet? I.e. is it chargable? I have trawled through the documentation on the Microsoft Website and even spoken directly with a Microsoft Sales representative and I get conflicting information.

For example you can see this on the MS Website:- [Azure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuGcN.png). But the MS representative was adamant that it would be charged. Obviously this has huge implications on cost for us. In fact, as ingress traffic is free, it may even prove cheaper to host the application outside the Azure cloud!

So, can someone set me straight, will this bandwidth be chargeable? If so, is there a way to avoid this charge? Through some special VNet peering or something?

Thanks Stack Overflow Community!

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after much experimentation, I have concluded that all traffic between Microsoft Services and your VM's is free. This is true, even if you connect to them from an external IP address provided that you connect to them from the **same** data centre (i.e. EU North). This was tested with over 6TB of upload from an Azure VM to Azure BLOB store without any cost incurred.

There is rumour that this might change when Microsoft Azure starts to charge for bandwidth between Availability Zones in early 2021. So, if you're relying on this information in the future I advise you to double check and experiment before you commit to nay huge data transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends of the region, if both VM and blob are really in the same region, and specially in the same vnet and availability zone it shouldn't be charged.

My recommendation is to test and if it happens to be charged you could open a support request to get the details, they will explain to you why it was charged and if there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong that you understand about the outbound data transfers. It means going out of the Azure data center. This is the basic limitation. All the Azure resources are located in the Azure data center. In the same region means in the same Azure data center and the data transfer is in the internal network of the data center without going through the Internet. So it is not charged. On the other hand, the different regions mean different data centers, then the data transfer will go through the Internet, and then it's charged.

To avoid the charge for the request from the VM to the Azure Blob Store. The first thing is to put both the VM and the Azure Blob Store in the same region. And you can use the private endpoint of the Azure Blob Store. In this way, the request will be in the same VNet and do not go through the Internet so that it's not chargeable. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-storage-portal) are the steps to achieve it.